# Hide the "Tap To Translate" Notification on Android

Tags: android, android-event, android-developer-api

If a user has set the Tap To Translate icon to appear on copying text, is there any way to disable it from appearing when text is copied in my app only?

The icons appears over the app as shown here: https://googleblog.blogspot.jp/2016/05/translate-where-you-need-it-in-any-app.html

At the moment I'm using ClipboardManager and copying the text using setText which seems to trigger it.  Is there some other method I can use to block it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't block another app from functioning. You know what is triggering its behavior (`ClipboardManager`) so don't use `ClipboardManager` and you won't trigger it.

Comment: Copying text is functionality I don't want to remove from the app.  Is there some other method that can be used to copy the text without triggering the notification?

Comment: Nope. Users who have the Translate app installed and have Tap to Translate enabled (since they *can* disable it within the Translate app if they want) obviously want that functionality.